# Re-Position MKMapView's userLocationView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I'm making an app that has a series of trails in the forest.  GPS is going to be off now and then by few dozen meters, so I'm trying to write some code that will "snap" the userLocationView to the trail (which is where the user likely is).

I've got some code working that scans the nearby trails, determines the probable location of the user, and gets the CLLocationCoordinate2D for it.

Now I need to apply that location to the userLocationView.  I thought that this would work, but it doesn't seem to:

```
userLocationAnnotation.coordinate = myDerivedCoordinate;
```

I realize I could probably create my own annotation, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapView` gets the user location directly from `CLLocationManager`, and there isn't a documented way to intercept this interaction. Doing so would be more work than adding your own annotation, and a cause for app rejection. Also, it doesn't make sense to redefine correct information provided by the system. That's why `mapView.userLocation` is a `MKUserLocation` with a readonly location property.

So you have to create your own, roughly:

- Set `mapView.showsUserLocation = false;`
- Create and start a location manager

  `self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new]; self.locationManager.delegate = self; [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`
- Add/replace your own blue dot annotation from `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` of the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

You can get the blue dot graphic (and probably the pulsating circles) with the UIKit-Artwork-Extractor. For the pulsating effect add to the `MKAnnotationView` a `UIImageView` with the different frames, or take one circle and use `UIView animateWithDuration` with a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` for the `view.transform` property.